# Conditionally using a SQL Temp Table throws errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a (not normalized) legacy SQL database and am working on a task to gather code from one of several similar tables.  I want to execute a lot of identical code against the #Temp table, but the tables it draws from are very dissimilar (with some columns being the same).

My code is:

```
IF @Variable = 'X'
BEGIN
   SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM TABLE1 WHERE Condition1 = @Condition
END

IF @Variable = 'Y'
BEGIN
   SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM TABLE2 WHERE Condition1 = @Condition
END
```

At this point, I execute some common code.  There is quite a lot and I want to just use #Temp, not have another IF condition with the code copied in multiple times.  I cannot really declare the table ahead of time (it is very wide - and they are not the same) and I cannot really normalize the DB (the legacy system is far to 'mature' and my time frame is far to small).  Also, at the end of the query, the #Temp table is used for creating new rows back in the original table (so again, I cannot just declare the common parts).

At this point, I cannot make my stored proc because

> There is already an object named '#Temp' in the database.

This error highlights the 2nd IF block.  Adding a DROP TABLE #Temp in the IF block does not help either.  So I'm having to offload the work in additional SPROCs or repeat the code in conditional statements.  For readability, I don't like either of these options.

Any way to use #Temp within multiple IF blocks as above ( I really have more IF conditions, only 2 shown to give an idea of the issue).

[Example SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/82a27/2)

Comment: Does `TABLE1` and `TABLE2` have the same structure (columns, datatypes)?

Comment: @Lamak no, only a few columns are the same.  I have edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: I find it weird that if the resulting `#Temp` table is so different, the rest of the code can be the same

Comment: Legacy systems always have weird issues (you never know what is needed in the future).  Imagine there are 50 columns, and 10 are the same.  I want to work with those 10, and then put the rows back in the original table as new rows... with all other columns the same.

Comment: If 10 columns are the same, then you can list those columns and create the exact temp table. I don't see the issue there

Comment: That is starting to appear to be the most readable option.  However, these tables are also very deep (in addition to wide), and I am not keen on having to go to them twice (once for common values, then join again later to insert the new ones).  But yes, using a declared #temp with only the common columns is looking like the solution.  I will try that and see how performance is. (Still hoping for a solution where I can pull the whole row).

Comment: In addition to what @Lamak has said, it would not only solve your issue, it is a much better solution, what is the point in putting 40 columns of data into a temp table if you can't use them?

Comment: @GarethD I need all that original data to create new records.

Comment: @Paul I mean that your code should have this structure: `CREATE TABLE #Temp(<list of common columns here>)` and then your `IF` should be something like: `IF @Variable = 'X' BEGIN INSERT INTO #Temp SELECT <list of common columns here> FROM TABLE1`, `IF @Variable = 'Y' BEGIN INSERT INTO #Temp SELECT <list of common columns here> FROM TABLE2`. No need to insert twice or anything like that

Comment: @Lamak I understand what you say.  But I have to insert the entire transformed record back into the original table.  So the 2 hits for seeking the record are once for the common values, then again for the rest of the row after I have the common values.  Actually... that creates a new problem.  At the time of insert, now I will have to write out which values come from which table (#Temp or Table1)... and effectively type out all the absurdly long lists of columns D:  This problem is really deeper than it looks.

Comment: Added SQL Fiddle demonstrating issue to assist with finding the answer. See post.